# Can I use SQL Server Authentication for Central Management Servers?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, central-management-server

I have set up a Central Management Server in SQL Server. When I try to add a new Registered Server to this Central Management Server, I only have the options to use **Windows Authentication** or **Active Directory Integrated Authentication**. Is there a way to connect to these Registered Servers using **Sql Server Authentication**?

This option does exist when connecting to a local server group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMS Drawback: Windows Authentication Only, And Only Your Login

Central Management Servers and subordinate registered servers can be registered only by using Windows Authentication.

See:

- [Create a New Registered Server (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188231.aspx) in the documentation
- [Central Management Server (CMS) – A Hidden Gem](https://dbabulldog.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/central-management-server-cms-a-hidden-gem/) by Dan Taylor.

Comment: You can start SSMS with a different account to circumvent issues where one account has not been granted the rights to login to a SQL instance.